# Firebase Function - query Firestore after OnCreate function

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to query a Firestore Document to retrieve a single field after a onCreate function.

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
const db = admin.firestore();

exports.logActivities = functions.firestore
.document("AccountLog/{docID}")
.onCreate(async (snap, context) => { 
    const newValues = snap.get('newBalace');

    console.log(newValues);



    const query = db.collection('iniAccounts');
    const querySnapshot = await query.get();
    const initialValues = querySnapshot.docs.map(document => (document.data()));

    console.log(initialValues);
});
```

The collection that i'm querying only has one document with 2 fields. When I execute the code above the "document.data()" retrieves all the fields and values for the document.

```
[ { cStartingBalance: '288',
    cStartingDate: '12/30/2019' } ]
```

The only field I need is the *cStartingBalance*. I have tried several solutions but none have retrieved just the *cStartingBalance* value.

Since the goal is to compare the *newValues* with the *initialValues*, is there a different approach that i should be taking? Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do here.  Are you saying you're going to assume this query only ever returns one document, and you want a value in a field of that document?  And there's never going to be 0 or 2 or more documents?  Seems like you could pretty easily just reach into that one element of the `initialValues` array...

Comment: Doug, you are correct the value i'm trying to retrieve is in a collection that will only have one document. Although i could retrieve the whole document, i could not figure out how to pull out that one value. @Peter-Haddad provided the code that eluded me. Thank you. console.log(initialValues[0].cStartingBalance);

Comment: Collection queries are intended to get zero or more documents from a collection. If you only ever need one document, there's no need to make a  query for it.   Just call out the one document by its ID and get() it individually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will be more clear and concise if you just `get()` the single document by its known ID.  For example:

```
const initialValues = await db.collection('iniAccounts').doc('document_id').get();
const data = initialValues.data()
if (!data) {
    // no document found - determine what you want to do
}
else {
    const cStartingBalance = initialValues.data().cStartingBalance;
}
```

This code assumes that you have a single document called 'document_id' in the in the 'iniAccounts' collection.

Comment: Thanks Doug. I tried that initially but kept running into an error on the _initialValues.cStartingBalance;_ 

Property 'cStartingBalance' does not exist on type 'DocumentSnapshot<DocumentData>'.

Which lead me to try using the route i listed in my original post.

Comment: Actually I typed it wrong.  There should be a call to `.data()` in there, since you need that to get the raw document data out of the snapshot (just like you are now).  Edited.  This is the preferred solution if you only need one document.

Comment: I just placed that in and am getting _initialValues.data().cStartingBalance;_ error on .data() "Object is possibly 'undefined'."

Comment: Edited - you should also check to see if the document actually exists.  If not, you will need to determine how you want to handle this case.  You would have a similar problem with an empty array if you performed the query in your question.

Comment: Doug, it worked when i added the "!" after .data()

const cStartingBalance = initialValues.data()!.cStartingBalance;

Comment: You can do that too, but it will crash if that document doesn't exist, because you'll be accessing a property of an undefined value.  I suggest checking first, as TypeScript also suggests.

Comment: Thank you for all your help. it is much appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome.  I will appreciate an upvote and marked correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you query a document, it will retrieve everything inside that document. If you are getting this list and want to access `cStartingBalance`, then you can do:

```
console.log(initialValues[0].cStartingBalance);
```